# Is it possible to use Spring @Autowired in Liferay hook?

Tags: spring, hook, liferay-6, autowired

I wonder if it is possible to have a bean form xml file injected by @Autowired somehow into Liferay hook. In this particular case I'm using UpgradeProcess hook. My project is already configured for using Spring with liferay, I can decode xml with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext's getBean("bean name") method, but it would be much nicer if this had happened automatically.

greetz!

Comment: Could you post an example how you are using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with your web.xml and contextConfigLocation ? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I've got rid of that code and can't restore it from SVN as we have moved our sources to another repository. But I understand you, as I've spent a couple of days trying go use Spring in Liferay :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible denu.

Configure your application's `web.xml` listener class as `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and place `applicationContext.xml` in the `WEB-INF` folder. It will pick the respective beans from your `applicationContext.xml` and you can autowire those objects in your beans.

Cheers